# jQuery is not passing custom headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, header

I have run through the gauntlet of documentation and google links (including Stack Overflow) related to sending headers with jQuery, but none of them have worked.  I am inspecting the request with Fiddler and FireBug, and neither show the custom headers.

I am pretty new to jQuery, so maybe all of the answers assume some knowledge of includes that I do not know about.

My ultimate goal is to call a RESTful service that requires the username/password combo be in the header (the primary reason for this question), once authenticated call another web service to get a secure token to use in a newly created cookie, and then redirect the user to another site that requires this secure cookie for authentication. (I hate Single-Sign-On integration)

Here is my HTML file that includes the (downloaded) jQuery and custom JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jquery.form-3.51.0.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/login.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="/rest/user/authenticate" id="loginLink">click to launch</a>
</br>
</br>
                <form id="loginForm" method="GET" action="/rest/user/authenticate">
                        User ID:<br>
                        <input type="text" style="width:100px;" size="16" id="user" name="user" value="" /><br>
                        Password:<br>
                        <input type="password" style="width:100px;" size="16" id="password" name="password" /><br><br>

                        <input style="cursor: hand" type="submit" border="0" align="middle" name="" value='Log in' /><br>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to add headers with a form (using both beforeSend and headers by commenting one out at a time):

```
var frm = $('#loginForm');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('BLAH', 'test-value');},
        //headers: {"BLAH": "test-value"},

        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error");
        }

    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

I thought maybe it was some limitation of submitting a form, so I also tried to get a custom header from clicking on a link, but that does not include the headers either.

```
$('#"loginLink"').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
            url: '/rest/user/authenticate',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            //headers: {"BLAH": "test-value"},
            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('BLAH', 'test-value');},
            success: function () { },
            error: function () { },
    });
});
```

The requests are being sent to my RESTful service, but the headers are not being included.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
    Sean

Comment: How do you know that the header isn't being set? Have you looked at the HTTP request via the browser developer tools?

Comment: Yes, from the first paragraph above: **I am inspecting the request with Fiddler and FireBug, and neither show the custom headers.**

Comment: Your ajax code works fine for me and sets the `'BLAH'` header

Comment: Oh sorry :)  Well the mechanism does work; I use it all the time.

Comment: @charlietfl what browser are you using, and how are you confirming that the header is included?

Comment: @Pointy no worries, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Firefox...confirm in Firebug, Chrome confirm in dev tools. Fine in both. Tested it from console while on this page

Comment: One more thing to double-check: are you completely sure that your `.submit()` handler is being called? Have you put a `console.log()` call in there? Note that if `$("#loginForm")` doesn't match any elements, jQuery won't produce any errors but your code wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Oh and on that note: a quick experiment would be to move your "login.js" `<script>` tag to right before the `</body>` closing tag (assuming that's where your code is).

Comment: @Pointy good question on the "is it being called?". I have added some console.log(""); entries, and so far I cannot get them to display on the Chrome dev tools console. Odd that @charlietfl says he used my exact code above and it works for them. `$('#"loginLink"').click(function(){
    console.log("clicking *** ");
` Since I saw that this was not logging, I updated my HTML to not include the URLs, and instead added those manually in the login.js file. Now I get some errors on the page: **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /jsp/blah** So some progress made.

Comment: is this a cross domain or cross port request?

Comment: No, the JSP starts at example.com/jsp/login.jsp and then the service is at example.com/rest/user/authenticate

Comment: I have changed my JS functions to output a console message at the start of the file (which I see in the console), but when I click submit or on the link, I do not see the entries for those functions. `frm.submit(function (ev) {
    console.log("forming ****");
... }` I never see the console message after clicking submit on the form, but I do see that my 'frm' variable is loaded with the form. Any ideas on why my frm.submit method is not being called?

Comment: Although, when I try to output variables of my form object, I get 'undefined'. `var frm = $('#loginForm');
console.log("form.method = " + frm);
console.log("form.method = " + frm.attr('action'));` results in the console output of `form = [object Object]
form.method = undefined`

Comment: Above, @Pointy suggested that I put the <script> tags just above the </body> tag, once this was done on my part, I was able to get over this hump, and the headers were included.  Thanks @Pointy!  If you'd like to submit an 'answer' below, I'll set it as the answer, and give you credit for it (unless there is an easier way to give you credit for the help).  Thanks for the help all who contributed!